# How to compute the following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I have tried mathematica to compute this integral, but I have found no answer.

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\lambda x) x^{n} dx $$ for $\lambda > 0$.

I have a feeling that it is

$$ \frac{n!}{\lambda^{n+1}} $$ based on my assumption that the indefinite integral results in upper incomplete Gamma function and at the limits $0$ and $\infty$, the upper incomplete Gamma function results in complete Gamma function, and $0$, respectively. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you studied Gamma function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: I am pretty sure that there should be no minus sign in the value of the integral, assuming $\lambda>0$.

Comment: Ah now I realize how simple was it. I was coming from a problem involving Gamma distributions and ended up at this integral. However, I didn't realize it's Gamma function  

Comment: Please don't use tags that you don't know about. `incompleteness` is entirely inappropriate for this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know about gamma function, then the substitution $t = \lambda x$ gives you
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \exp(-\lambda x)x^n dx = \frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}\int\limits_0^\infty \exp(-t)t^n dt = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\lambda^{n+1}} = \frac{n!}{\lambda^{n+1}}.
$$
Thus, the same result can be easily obtained integrating by parts

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very simple. Didn't realize I was ending up at Gamma function.